# Virtual Memory and Virtual Address in Linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, virtual-memory

I am currently studying about virtual memory in operating system and I have few questions.

1. Is swap partition or swap file same as virtual memory in terms of Linux?
2. If yes, then in case I've no swapping enabled in my Linux system, does that mean my system has no virtual memory?
3. I have also read that virtual memory makes system more secure because with virtual memory, CPU generates virtual addresses which are then translated to actual physical addresses by MMU, therefore securing the system because no process can actually interact with the actual physical memory. So if I just enable swapping on my Linux system, will my CPU start generating virtual addresses and currently it's directly generating physical addresses as I have no swap partition?
4. How does CPU know if virtual memory is present or not?

Comment: You first need to read a good [textbook on operating systems](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Then you need to understand Linux [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/). See also [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and provide some [mre] for your next questions on StackOverflow

Comment: Notice that **Linux is [open source](https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source) : you can download and study the source code** of its [kernel](http://kernel.org/) and improve it. See https://kernelnewbies.org/ and https://linuxfromscratch.org/ and [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having no swap file/partition doesn't imply that you don't have virtual memory. Modern operating-systems always use paging/virtual memory no matter what.

> Is swap partition or swap file same as virtual memory in terms of Linux?

No swap file and virtual memory is not the same in terms of any OS. Virtual memory just says that all memory accesses are going to be translated by the MMU using the page tables. Modern OSes always use paging.

> If yes, then in case I've no swapping enabled in my Linux system, does that mean my system has no virtual memory?

Your system certainly has virtual memory. To use long mode (64bits mode), the OS  must enable paging. I doubt that you have a system old enough to not use paging. Page swapping to the hard-disk is not virtual memory. It is more like a feature of virtual memory that can be used to extend physical memory because a page which isn't required immediatly can be swapped to the hard-disk momentarily.

> I have also read that virtual memory makes system more secure because with virtual memory, CPU generates virtual addresses which are then translated to actual physical addresses by MMU, therefore securing the system because no process can actually interact with the actual physical memory. So if I just enable swapping on my Linux system, will my CPU start generating virtual addresses and currently it's directly generating physical addresses as I have no swap partition?

Your computer certainly has paging/virtual memory enabled. Having no swap partition doesn't mean that you don't have virtual memory. Paging can also be used to avoid fragmentation of RAM and for security. You are right that paging is securing your system because the page tables prevent a process from accessing the memory of another process. It also has ring privilege on a page to page basis which allows to differentiate between kernel mode and user mode code.

> How does CPU know if virtual memory is present or not?

The OS just enables paging by setting a bit in a control register. Then the CPU starts blindly translating every memory accesses using the MMU.

Comment: i think it makes all the sense. It just raised one more question. I read that "when your ram runs out of available space and a higher priority tasks arrives, os transfers some of your programs to virtual memory and brings the higher priority task into main memory". Now in linux, "Swap space in Linux is used when the amount of physical memory (RAM) is full"

Comment: So doesn't it mean that swap space is same as virtual memory? Are you saying that there are two types of virtual memory. One, virtual memory that will always be there to achieve paging and protection and another virtual memory is the swap space. where programs are swapped to when you run out of ram?

Comment: I didn't say the first thing you said I said. The OS doesn't transfer unused pages to virtual memory. It transfers unused pages to the hard-disk. It can do that because the present bit is set on a page to page basis unlike with segmentation where the present is set on a segment basis. If a memory access attempts to access a page which is marked as not present, the CPU raises a page fault and the OS either brings the page on the hard-disk to RAM or kill the process (if the memory access was not legal).

Comment: When physical memory is full, the OS takes unused pages and brings them in the hard-disk marking them as not present in the page table.

Answer (score 1):

No. Swap file is not the same as virtual memory.

Once the firmware/kernel sets up the necessary registers and/or in-memory data structures and switches the processor mode, virtual memory mappings are used for accessing the physical memory.

Yes, the inability of processes to refer to memory locations without a mapping allows the kernel to employ isolation and access control mechanisms.

Through active mappings, different virtual addresses can map to the same physical memory region at different times. The kernel can maintain the illusion that a larger amount of memory is available that the capacity of the actual physical memory, where only a subset of the virtual memory resides in the physical memory at any given time. The rest is stored in the swap file.

Accesses to virtual addresses where the corresponding data is currently in the swap file are trapped by the kernel (via a page fault) and might lead to the kernel *swapping* the data in, and *swapping* some other data from physical memory out.

If you disable the swap file, the kernel has no place store the swapped out data. This reduces the amount of virtual memory available.

Comment: "Swap file is not the same as virtual memory", then what is? From what i've read, "Linux can use either a normal file in the filesystem or a separate partition for swap space." and the swap space is same as virtual memory. Now I am not saying that swap file IS the virtual memory. What i'm saying is that "Does having swap-file/swap-partition means i have virtual memory and in case i have no swap-file or no swap-partition, that implies my system has no virtual memory"?

Comment: You might not even have a disk and the kernel would still set up virtual to physical mappings. The swap file only increases the size of the available virtual memory.